# How to say that a word has many the same letters?

Tags: letters-of-the-alphabet

How to say that a word has many the same letters?

For example in the word "carrot" I should say:

- two "R"s.
  or
- two r letters.

Answer (score 1):

Words which do not usually have plurals sometimes have an apostrophe when a plural form is written.

*It is a nice idea, but there are a lot of **if's**.*

Apostrophes are used in the plurals of letters, and sometimes of numbers and abbreviations.

*He writes **b's** instead of **d's**.*

Michael Swan *PRACTICAL ENGLISH USAGE*

Answer (score 0):

There is no particular name for them. Double letter word seems to be how they are referred to in scholarly texts.